# Help me Choose a Rasberry Pi board

Tags: raspberry-pi

I wanted to run Image Processing and 4-5 different sensors on a single Rasberry Pie Board. So what board should be sufficient for the work ? I couldn't choose as I am new to IOT and have very little knowledge Rasberry pie

Comment: Hi Welcome to HW Recs! Your question in it's current form is too broad. Please try to **narrow down the nature of image processing** (e.g. 4K facial recognition = higher spec board vs. 720p simple homographic detection = less specs) that you plan on doing and the **maximum price** you are willing to pay for such a Pi board.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it out by buying a Pi Zero W to test the requirements you need since they are very cheap.

Then after you ascertained your requirements go for what you need. Stick with the Zero or get a more powerful one.

I believe the Raspberry Pi 3 should be able to do what you want but I would recommend that you get a Raspberry Pi 4 with 2GB at least. That way you have both the processing power and the memory to run almost anything you throw at it
Besides, if you then decide to re-use the Pi on another project, you know you have the power for it. 
The only drawback is the Pi 4 huge power demand of a 3A PSU while the 3 needs 2.5A and the Zero W needs 0.3A (this is just the boards without any sensors)